Poppler installation in windows
I have tried to install poppler using conda install -c conda-forge poppler  it get successfully installed in my environment pdftotext version 22.12.0, but while running my layout detection code it throw this error pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
Is there any solution?

Also i tried to installed the zip file and adding bin file in my system variable path, sadly it also don't work and other than this also solution ?


Please edit your question and add a small snippet of code, the recreates your error
